# Error '7867': You already have the database open"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to open a second database so that I can run a macro in it but it gives me an

> Error 7867: You already have the database open"

the code is below. it doesn't normally give me any problems

```
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With objAccess
.OpenCurrentDatabase"C:\Personnal\investment\4125_2.accdb", False
.Run "ComboShortPositionMultiThread", 12, 20, 2
End With
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is the database open in Access?

Comment: no, but if I ignore the error the funtion still works, not sure why. Im not sure what the point of this error is.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *...trying to open a second database...*?  Does the first database use the same `objAccess` object?  Is it open in the same process?